# When sending NULL for saving in MySQL DB but it is stored as null string instead of DbNull

Tags: c#, mysql, json, serialization

I'm in a weird situation where i'm unable to find why even sending proper NULL from C# code side, my db column **[Having JSON type and has default null value]** is storing null instead of DbNull.

I'm trying to save the data againts one JSON column that i have in DB side.[image]

My C# code at data layer :

```
var options = new MySqlParameter("@pOptions", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(JsonSerializer.Serialize(settings.Options, options)) ? JsonSerializer.Serialize(settings.Options, options) : null);
```

As you can see in above image for options column, the row below null string is having dbnull same and im trying for the same but, unable to do so.

Any help or pointers are welcomed.

Comment: Please add your relevant C# code.

Comment: @Fildor Question updated with C# code as well.

Comment: Ok, one observation, one suspicion: Observation - this code serializes twice. You don't need that. Suspicion: The serializer output is `"null"` which is neither `null` nor empty.

Comment: @Fildor thanks for pointer. Solved it right away. Thanks

Comment: For a real null you need to send `DBNull.Value`

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem.  Silly me. Used following thing.

```
settings.Options != null ? JsonSerializer.Serialize(settings.Options, options) : null
```

And it worked.